# clustering algorithm for dynamic data

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, k-means

What is the algorithm for clustering , when the data arrives dynamically .That is as soon an data arrives the old cluster centroid should be modified bit to accommodate new feature and also if needed it create new centroid.

I know k-mean algorithm but we need to define cluster and it is static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this: [Sequential K-Means clustering](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos436/Duda/C/sk_means.htm)